# facebook-app: share-button and iFrame resize code together

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is it possible to have a share button (the old one) and the iFrame resize function in the same app? It seems the two javascript libraries don't work together.

### Update

I finally replaced the old share button with a FB.ui feed dialog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: you could nest the share button in a separate iframe, so the library won't need to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could nest the share button in a separate iframe, so the library won't need to work together